# IntelliJ IDEA Console Folding with Wildcards?

Tags: intellij-idea

**Short Question:** Can I specify wildcards for custom console folding? If so, what is the syntax?

**Long Question:**
IntelliJ has a really nifty plugin (that comes built in) which allows you to fold lines in console output (and specify a blacklist/whitelist of when or when not to do this)

[image: Console Folding]

However I am unsure how (if it's even possible) to specify a wildcard character. a lot of lines begin with a timestamp, like so

`1, Jan, 2012, 10:00:00,000 DEBUG`

Which i'd like to fold, by DEBUG, using something like

`* DEBUG`

I know I could restrict the log level to INFO only, but these lines are useful if a test fails, and then I can expand them at will.

Is there a way to do this, or should I start looking for the IntelliJ feature request page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't use wildcards at all. When you add a new folding pattern you get a prompt saying:

`Enter a substring of a console line you'd like to see folded:`

[image: Folding pattern]

Notice that it says "substring". Try to just write "DEBUG" there and see if it works.

Comment: "The Simplest Solution is often the best" Can't believe I missed this thanks

Comment: The image does not exist. Can you update the answer to fix this problem?

Comment: @JohnRed, the image is visible to me. Anyway, expended the text a little to reflect the screenshot

Comment: I just chucked a slash character in which was on every line anyway, this was for debugging xamarin on android.